# Cutting plaster walls

Tags: electrical, wiring

I have to rewire a old home that currently has knob and tube wiring. Would I be able to cut a small thin line all the way up the plaster wall in the middle of two studs, then use that small (1/4”) hole to grab onto the romex wire from the outlet box  and pull it up the wall and into the drop ceiling. Then I was going to make a California patch of drywall to cover the hole. Will all of this work?

Comment: usually you can fish it behind the lath.  Would help to know if the wall is hollow

Comment: tricky very tricky ..consider dropping a wire or rope from the top, to tie the cable to it and pull t up